# How do I use Square Bracket Notation to use multiple variables to call nested objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will use multiple variables to select the correct nested object, and then be able to manipulate it.

```
var group1 = {
        fred: {
            debt: 5,
            income: 2
        },
        suzy: {
            debt: 3,
            income: 5
        }
    },
    group2 = {
        molly: {
            debt: 4,
            income: 4
        },
        jason: {
            debt: 6,
            income: 1
        }
    };

function debtCheck(group, name) {
    console.log(group.name.debt);         ==>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debt' of undefined
    console.log(group[name].debt);        ==>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debt' of undefined
    console.log([group][name].debt);      ==>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debt' of undefined
    console.log([group[name]].debt);      ==>undefined
}

debtCheck('group1', 'fred');
```

The goal would be to have it display 5 in the console. If I only do one variable, it works fine.

```
function debtCheck(name) {
    console.log(group1[name].debt);
}

debtCheck('fred');
```

Hopefully I made it clear what I'm asking about. Thanks for the help!

Other thoughts I've had about it:
Is it that the base object can't be a variable? Or you can't have two variables in a row?

Comment: Put your `group1`, `group2`, etc. variables into another object, just like how you have `fred` and `suzy` inside of `group1`.

Comment: You're passing the first argument as a string rather than the object. Try `debtCheck(group1, 'fred');`. Also since the second param should be a string you need to access it via `group[name].debt`.

Comment: @JasonCust you should make this an answer.

Comment: @Pavlo no, this question should be closed for a typographical error (a 2 character change is relevant enough)

Comment: @SterlingArcher I don't agree. As explained in Jason's answer there is a problem with data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the first argument as a string rather than the object. Try `debtCheck(group1, 'fred');`. Also since the second param should be a string you need to access it via `group[name].debt`.

Some background material to help you regarding the first point: [passing values/references to a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions); and regarding the second point: [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

```js
var group1 = {
  fred: {
    debt: 5,
    income: 2
  },
  suzy: {
    debt: 3,
    income: 5
  }
};
var group2 = {
  molly: {
    debt: 4,
    income: 4
  },
  jason: {
    debt: 6,
    income: 1
  }
};

function debtCheck(group, name) {
  console.log(group[name].debt);
}

// debtCheck('group1', 'fred');
debtCheck(group1, 'fred');
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things. You have `group1` put in as a string and not an object. Second you can't use the dot notation when referencing objects by a specific variable name. You need to use square brackets.

Try:

```
function debtCheck(group, name) {
    console.log(group[name].debt);
 }

debtCheck(group1, 'fred');
```

Comment: This did the trick. I don't see why I didn't figure it out myself. Anyways. Thanks!